# Python Selenium find by xpath and validate ID

Tags: python, selenium, element

My goal is to find the Sync button and validate that the "listing-id"=x

```
<button id="user-sync" class="btn btn-warning btn-block" listing-id="3750512979321321472">Sync Now!</button>
```

I use the following xpath to locate the sync button but I'm unsure how to find the "listing-id".  I've tried to find by css selector but keep hitting errors.

```
userSync = price.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user-sync"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you find the element, you can use `userSync.get_attribute('listing-id')` to access the `listing-id`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.get_attribute` method on a web element. You already have the WebElement as `userSync`

Something like this :

```
attr_value = userSync.get_attribute('listing-id')
print (attr_value)
```